# Dyer–Lashof operations for more than 2 inputs

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, operads, chain-complexes, covering-spaces

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a topological operad and $X$ an algebra over it. Let the base ring be $\mathbb{Z}_2$. If $C_*$ denotes the singular chain complex over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the action of $\mathcal{O}$ gives us morphisms
$$\mu:C_*(\mathcal{O}(r))\otimes_{r} C_*(X)^{\otimes r}\to C_*(X)$$
where $\otimes_{r}$ means the tensor product over the group algebra $\mathbb{Z}_2\mathfrak{S}_r$ of the $r$th symmetric group. Now consider the covering $\mathcal{O}(r)\to \mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r$. For each simplex $s\in C_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)$ we choose one of the $r!$ lifts $\widetilde{s}$ and consider the map
$$\Phi:C_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)\times C_*(X)\to C_*(\mathcal{O}(r))\otimes_r C_*(X)^{\otimes r}, (s,a)\mapsto \widetilde{s}\otimes_r a^{\otimes r}.$$
We see a few things immediately:

1. This map is not a map of chain complexes, but linear in the first argument.
2. As we do not have to care about signs, we have $\tau_*a^{\otimes r}=a^{\otimes r}$ and the map is independent of the choice of lifts.
3. If $c\in C_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)$ and $a\in C_*(X)$ are cycles, then $\Phi(c,a)$ is a cycle.
4. If $c\in C_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)$ is a boundary and $a\in C_*(X)$ is a cycle, then $\Phi(c,a)$ is a boundary.

Putting all this together, we get a well-defined map
$$\Psi:H_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)\times C^{\text{cyc}}_*(X)\to H_*(C_*(\mathcal{O}(r))\otimes_r C_*(X)^{\otimes r})\stackrel{\mu}{\to}H_*(X).$$

Now if we have $r=2$ (so we only have a $2$-fold covering) we can even show:

5. If $c\in C_*(\mathcal{O}(r)/\mathfrak{S}_r)$ is a cycle and $a+a'\in C_*(X)$ is a boundary, then $\Phi(c,a)+\Phi(c,a')$ is a boundary.

This finally gives us a map
$$Q:H_*(\mathcal{O}(2)/\mathfrak{S}_2)\times H_*(X)\to H_*(X)$$
which is used to define Dyer–Lashof operations: If $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$ is the little $(n+1)$-cube operad, then $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}(2)/\mathfrak{S}_2\simeq \mathbb{R}P^n$ and each $e_i\in H_i(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ gives an operation $Q_i:H_p(X)\to H_{2p+i}(X)$.

I was wondering if the last ingredient, namely (5), is only true for $r=2$. I have not found a counterexample for $r=3$ (still, everything over $\mathbb{Z}_2$), but I also could not find a proof.

Comment: I think it is easier to look at $r$ a power of $2$, so the next case being $r=4$.  I believe that one should be able to get iterated Dyer-Lashof (Kudo-Araki rather since you are working at 2) operations.

Comment: Thank you! So do you think the statement is wrong for $r$ not being a power of $2$?

Comment: Well I only mean that the case $r$ being a power of 2 is the easiest case to investigate.  Presumably for other values of $r$, we would get something related to Kudo-Araki operations via the product.